# Tracing Castle Windsor Resolution of Type

Tags: castle-windsor

Is there any way to trace exactly what Castle Windsor is doing when resolving a type?

I am looking for a TraceSource name, or log4net (etc.) logger name. If this does not exist where is the best place to hook into the framework to provide my own logging code?

Reason being is we have deployed the exact same build/config of our software to two different virtual servers (both servers created from the same image), and one of them "works" and the other doesnt.

On the failing deployment, our own logs show that a component that was expected to be injected to another is null. On the other machine, the logs show everything is healthy.

I am lost as to why this might happen, and was looking to trace the castle container resolving code.

EDIT:
Running Castle Windsor Release 2.0 on .NET 3.5 SP1

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try hooking to the kernel's `DependencyResolving` event:

```
container.Kernel.DependencyResolving += (componentModel, dependencyModel, dependency) => {};
```

Or adding a `ISubDependencyResolver`:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new MyDependencyResolver());
```